# Beneficial to check whether lookup value is present

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have five columns that contain product numbers.
For each column i have multiple xlookup formulas in place.
Not all five columns with product numbers contain a product number in each row however.
Is it beneficial to first check whether the lookup value is present to speed up the process?

Comment: Maybe *Improve lookup calculation* time article is helpful? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#improve-lookup-calculation-time

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear if the 5 columns are the source data for the lookup, or the "search term", or the destination (i.e. where the lookup formulae are entered). Also, are you looking up vertically (along a column) or horisontally (along a row).

Either way, if the value your are looking for (the search term) is sometimes blank, it might be useful to include something like `=IF(A2="",NA(), XLOOKUP(A2, ...))`.

If the source data has random blanks, there's not much you can do, except perhaps to sort the data so that the blanks sit at the bottom.

If you are searching along a row, and the whole might be blank, AND there are several blank rows AND the spreadsheet is particularly slow, you might want to add a single "Is blank row?" column e.g. `=A2&B2&..E2 =""` or `=COUNTBLANK(A2:E2)>4` which you can then check before each XLOOKUP.

Lastly, if you are looking up the same value several times, each time returning a different corresponding index value, consider doing a separate MATCH() lookup in one column, then using the returned index number with INDEX() for each subsequent "lookup". I.e. search once, get reference index, use INDEX to reference each corresponding value. If you are using Office 365, you can also use LET to save a column e.g. `=LET(x, MATCH(A2,data1), INDEX(data2, x) + INDEX(data3, x)`.